# Закодировать несколько слов числами

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Просто стало интересно, нет конкретной задачи. Допустим, есть набор из некоторого количества слов или фраз (50-60), длина слова - в пределах 30 символов, слова не могут повторяться.

Существует ли алгоритм, по которому каждому слову можно было бы сопоставить некоторое число (всегда одинаковое), с минимальным количеством символов, так, чтобы минимизировать риск совпадения этих чисел?

Comment: Если текст заранее обозрим, то почему бы просто не пронумеровать все уникальные слова. Если нет - то посмотрите темы хеширования, но там разумеется бывают коллизии

Answer (score 0):

Так как слово является последовательностью символов, вы можете попробовать использовать алгоритм Хаффмана: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Код_Хаффмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

В этом случае будет построено бинарное дерево с кодами символов, зависящих от частоты употребления данного символа.

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно, есть такие алгоритмы - называются алгоритмами хэширования. Как справедливо заметили там есть проблема коллизии, но ее вероятность минимальна.

Почитайте про алгоритмы SHA-1, MD5 и SHA-256. Для вашей задачи вполне будет достаточно SHA-1 - 160 битное число. Вероятность коллизии на вашем словаре минимальна.